# Border is slightly larger than image on the bottom?

Tags: html, css, border, sidebar

[image] Here you will be able to see the issue. The left and right sides of the border fit perfectly, as well as the top of the image, even though I didn't screenshot that part. The bottom doesn't fit as tightly - it's slightly bigger than the image.

Here is where I believe the problems may be. Please tell me what I messed up on.

```
sidebar { 
    display: block; 
    position:fixed; 
    width:120px; 
    background:{sidebar color}; 
    border: 15px #fff solid; 
    padding:0px; 
    overflow:hidden;
    left:250px; 
    top:140px;
}
```

Or this, which is for the image in the sidebar div:

```
width:120px;
height:120px;
padding: 0px;
position:center;
```

Comment: I would recommend inserting the image directly into the question rather than referencing it with a hyperlink. In my opinion it helps support better formatting and helps for more rapid view of the information available to people that want to help you including myself.

Comment: `position:center;` is not valid CSS

Answer (score 1):

Extra space on the bottom of containers like what you are describing is often caused by either line-height (font size) of inline elements inside of the container, or vertical margins inside of the container element somewhere.

In other words, there's probably an element inside your sidebar div which has either margins set or something that is an inline or inline-block element that has to be at least a certain height.

Without seeing the HTML code you have it's hard to provide a specific fix, but you can try setting the property **line-height:0;** on the elements inside of the sidebar div, or **margin:0;** as well.

Some combination of line-height:0; margin:0; and font-size:0; should do the trick to eliminate that extra space on the bottom of the border.